# OpenSCAD like functionality with Mathematica?

Tags: graphics3d, 3d-printing

I keep seeing reference to use of *Mathematica* as a CAD tool (for instance, [this](http://www.makerbot.com/support/guides/design/)).  I'd like to use it as such if feasible, but I'm having trouble locating equivalents of the functionality I use in my current design tool, OpenSCAD.

I know how to create simple shapes (`Graphics3D[]`, `Cylinder[]`, etc.) and I'm aware that *Mathematica* can export to STL format. But does *Mathematica* have equivalents of the following OpenSCAD functions, or is it the wrong tool for the kind of thing I'm trying to do?

- linear_extrude()
- union()
- intersection()
- difference()
- translate()
- rotate()

Comment: Boolean operations on geometric objects are not supported (yet).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### UPDATE

With release of Mathematica 10 built-in functionality we have new things and continue to add - please see:

[Geometric Computation examples](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/geometric-computation/)

[Geometric Computation guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GeometricComputation.html)

[Especially: Derived Geometric Regions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DerivedRegions.html)

### OLDER

Quick answers to some points:

- [**Translate**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Translate.html)
- [**Rotate**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rotate.html)
- [**GeometricTransformation**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GeometricTransformation.html)

My guess is you are interested in the operations related to 3D printing. *Mathematica* provides computational approach - which is very general and allows to compute a lot of things. To see possibilities I would really recommend to watch [**Yu-Sung Chang**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/820) recent talk **"Scan, Convert, and Print: Playing with 3D Objects in Mathematica"**:

- [**Video**](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?channel=317&video=1453)
- [**Notebook**](http://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/wolfram-visualization-virtual-workshop-2013/PlayingWith3DObjectsInMathematica.zip)

In the notebook on **slide 12** you find how to define **Union**, **Difference**, **Intersection**. Quick sample from that slide for Difference between a cube and a sphere:

```
sphereQ[{x_, y_, z_}, r_, center_: {0, 0, 0}] := Norm[{x, y, z} - center] < r;

cubeQ[{x_, y_, z_}, r_] := (Abs[x] < r && Abs[y] < r && Abs[z] < r);

RegionPlot3D[
 cubeQ[{x, y, z}, 1] && \[Not] 
   sphereQ[{x, y, z}, 1, {1, 1, 1}], {x, -1, 2}, {y, -1, 2}, {z, -1, 
  2}, PlotRangePadding -> .5, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

You can do other neat things like computing and thickening thin surfaces - all this is in the video:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{1.16^v Cos[v] (1 + Cos[u]), -1.16^v Sin[
    v] (1 + Cos[u]), -2 1.16^v (1 + Sin[u])}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -15, 
  6}, Mesh -> False, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.5], 
 PlotPoints -> 35]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The approach described in that talk looks the closest to the feature set I was hoping to reproduce.

Answer (score 6):

Most of these are pretty easy in *Mathematica*. Here are a few to get you started:

```
Graphics3D[{Gray, 
  Translate[
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 0.5], {{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}]}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[{Gray, Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 0.5], 
  Rotate[Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 0.5], \[Pi]/2, {0, 1, 0}]},
  Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

```
extrude[p_Polygon, z_] := 
 Module[{pts = p[[1]]}, 
  Polygon /@ {Append[#, 0] & /@ pts, Append[#, z] & /@ pts, 
    Join[Append[#, 0] & /@ #, Append[#, z] & /@ Reverse[#]] & /@ 
     Partition[List @@ pts, 2, 1, 1]}]
pentagon = Polygon[Array[{Cos[2 \[Pi] #/5], Sin[2 \[Pi] #/5]} &, 5]];
Graphics3D[{Gray, extrude[pentagon, 2]}, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

A union is basically just a list of objects, but intersection and difference would take a bit more thought than I can spare tonight. I'm sure someone could cook it up in minutes, though.

Comment: It is worth noting that these are probably not printable objects. They aren't solid and their shell thickness is probably too thin to be translated into gcode. You can check this by limiting the plot range and inspecting the interior form.