# 3D Printing in Mathematica Tutorials

Tags: documentation, 3d-printing

Are there thorough tutorials on 3D printing for *Mathematica*? It seems that being able to export *Mathematica* files for 3D printing is unfortunately still a novelty, but it's vital for my business plans.

It would be much appreciated to specifically make

```
 ContourPlot3D[3 Sin[E^x] == (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(.5), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}]
```

3D printable for MakerBot. *Mathematica* would not allow using `Thickness` for `ContourPlot3D`, but did for `ParametricPlot3D`.

Comment: For some links to example-websites and articles check out [**this**](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/139463).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There're already some posts about 3D printing in this site, for example [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20964/1871), [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39879/1871), and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27728/1871).

For your specific question, there's no doubt that *Mathematica* allow using `Thickness` for `ContourPlot3D`, together with `ContourStyle`:

```
ContourPlot3D[3 Sin[E^x] == (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(.5), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, 
              ContourStyle -> {Thickness[0.2], Opacity[0.6]}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work with Mathematica 10.2 on OS X.

Comment: @shrx Sounds like another bug of v10. (The above code is tested in v9.0.1, and I haven't updated to v10 so far. ) Have you reported this to WRI?

Comment: I found out I can use `Extrusion` in v10 here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55021/6849