# 3D plot of a solid of revolution

Tags: plotting, rotation

I'm trying to rotate the area between the graphs of $y=3$ and $y=x^2$ around $y=1$. I'm not attempting to just find the area as that would just be `π Integral[9 - x^4]`, but rather I'm trying to create a 3D plot that I can print with a 3D printer.

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40953/7167)

Answer (score 4):

I can show you how to generate a [`RevolutionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RevolutionPlot3D.html) of your curve, but having no experience with 3D-printing, I don't know if the results will be in the form you need for 3D-printing.

First, rewrite your function so that it can be revolved about `y = 0`, because  `RevolutionPlot3D` is designed to revolve curves about an axis the passes trough the origin.

```
y[x_] := x^2 - 1
```

`RevolutionPlot3D`  also assumes the curve lies in the xz-plane, so the revolution should be made about the x-axis, not the default z-axis.

```
RevolutionPlot3D[y[t], {t, -Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3]},
  RevolutionAxis -> "x", Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Suspect he meant for the plot range to be `{1,Sqrt[3]}` (at least that gives something physically sensible) -- then you need to close the plot to make a solid..